# Prove that if $A \preceq B$, then $C^{A} \preceq C^{B}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

I am proving the following proposition from set theory:

> If $A \preceq B$, then $C^{A} \preceq C^{B}$.

Here is my proof. Suppose $A \preceq B$. Then there exists a one-one mapping $f: A \to B$. Define a function $\theta: C^{B} \to C^{A}$ such that for an arbitrary $\alpha \in C^{B}$ and $x \in A$, the following relation holds:
\begin{equation*}
\left[\theta\left(\alpha\right)\right]\left(x\right) = \alpha\left(f\left(x\right)\right).
\end{equation*}
We need to prove that $\theta$ is onto. That is, for all $\beta \in C^{A}$, there exists an $\alpha \in C^{B}$, such that $\beta = \theta\left(\alpha\right)$. This is equivalent to saying that for an arbitrary $\beta \in C^{A}$, there is an $\alpha \in C^{B}$, for an arbitrary $x \in A$,
\begin{equation*}
\beta\left(x\right) = \left[\theta\left(\alpha\right)\right]\left(x\right) = \alpha\left(f\left(x\right)\right),
\end{equation*}
or,
\begin{equation*}
\langle f\left(x\right), \beta\left(x\right) \rangle \in \alpha.
\end{equation*}
It is equivalent to proving that for each $\beta \in C^{A}$, there exists an $\alpha \in C^{B}$, such that
\begin{equation*}
\left\{\langle f\left(x\right),\beta\left(x\right) \rangle: x \in A\right\} \subseteq \alpha.
\end{equation*}
As $f: A \to B$ is one-one, it is unlikely that $x_{1} \neq x_{2}$ and $f\left(x_{1}\right) = f\left(x_{2}\right)$. Thus, $\left\{\langle f\left(x\right),\beta\left(x\right) \rangle: x \in A\right\}$ is indeed a subset of a function in $C^{B}$. Thus, $\theta$ is onto, and there exists a one-one function $\gamma: C^{A} \to C^{B}$, and $C^{A} \preceq C^{B}$.

Is this argument solid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you’re assuming the axiom of choice, showing that there is a surjection $\theta:C^B\to C^A$ does **not** prove that $C^A\preceq C^B$; you really do need to show that there is an injection from $\varphi:C^A\to C^B$. Fortunately, what you did in the last paragraph can easily be adapted to do this.

Fix $c_0\in C$. For each $\alpha\in C^A$ define $\varphi(\alpha)\in C^B$ as follows:

$$\big(\varphi(\alpha)\big)(b)=\begin{cases}
\alpha(a),&\text{if }b=f(a)\text{ for some }a\in A\\
c_0,&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

In other words, $\alpha=\big(\varphi(\alpha)\upharpoonright f[A]\big)\circ f$ for each $\alpha\in C^A$. It’s straightforward to verify that $\varphi$ is injective.

(If $C=\varnothing$, we cannot choose $c_0\in C$, but in that case $C^A=\varnothing=C^B$.)

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct, although it seems a bit hard to read. Here is an alternative shorter proof:

Given $f:A\to B$ injective, $f$ is a bijection onto its image, which we call $D$. Thus, $C^A$ and $C^D$ have the same cardinal (you can find a bijection from $C^D$ to $C^A$ by composing with $f$). Moreover, $C^{D} \preceq C^{B}$, because to each function $f:D\to C$ we can assign an extension $F:B\to C$, and obviously if two functions are different, their extensions are different too, so we have a one-one map from $C^D$ to $C^B$.

Edit: I assumed you could use the axiom of choice, but as
[Brian M. Scott](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/12042/brian-m-scott)
says in his answer, if that is not the case it is not enough to find a surjection from $C^B$ to $C^A$.